# Can't get AWS ELB to server SSL on hosted EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I setup an ELB to accept http/https traffic with a security group to allow all http/https traffic. Instead of pointing the domain to the EC2 IP, it is instead pointed at the alias of the ELB.

The EC2 is setup to accept http/https from any location at the moment, amongst ssh from my computer.

The target group is setup to forward traffic via https to the instances, and health check is performed via http. The targets show as healthy. In addition, the DNS for the ELB, and the website, throws a 502 error, and is unsecure accessible via https.

When I configure the target group to forward traffic via http to the instances, and the health check is performed via http, the targets still show as healthy. The ELB DNS / website is accessible for the ELB, though https still throws an unsecure warning.

Port 443 shows as closed. I have apache setup to listen to both port 80 and port 443 in order to serve the website. Normally, I would have the certificates on the server and would route port 80 to port 443 to serve them, so that's why they're both enabled.

Comment: Use `Client -> HTTPS -> ELB -> HTTP -> EC2`, use HTTP health check. If you receive certificate warning, then your ELB certificate is not correct.

Comment: The current setup is the domain is pointed to the DNS of the ELB. The ELB routes all HTTP / HTTPS traffic to the target group as HTTP traffic. I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, as if the port isn't opened.

Comment: Revert your configuration to the point where you had an unsecure warning in browser.

Comment: That may be with reverting to pointing the domain directly at the IP instead of at the ELB. Otherwise, just ask for specific configurations and I'll provide them to help debug this. This is the first time using AWS for certs. Normally I have a 3rd party do the certs and install them and include them in VHosts.

Comment: Your DNS has to point to ELB. After you do that, is the connection still refused?

Comment: Domain currently points to the IP, as you said to find the configuration that put me to the point where I had an insecure warning. I'll set the domain to point to the ELB and see what happens. I've been getting different results on different networks / computers.

Comment: DNS responses are cached, so it might take different times on different networks for changes to be noticed...

Comment: It looks like I typed my other domain as the value for the CNAME for www. I now get the right version of the website on https. In addition, I had to modify the apache VHost configuration to make sure it points the domain to the ELB instead of the localhost. Now I have SSL.